How do I implement in Spring a Eureka Server and Client that communicates using SSL with a custom configuration that doesn't verify hostname
I have a Java application with multiple services. I implemented a Eureka Server and my services register themselves in Eureka. Now I want to secure my Service Discovery Eureka using SSL with a custom truststore that reads the certificates from a vault and not from a file.
I have been trying to override SSL configuration with DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs but both my eureka client and eureka server seem to be ignoring my custom SSL config. They will try to validate hostname in certificate even if my custom SSL config uses a hostname verifier that ignores the hostname. Is this even possible ? Does anyone have an example of how to do this ?
